# How to read a orcFile with InputStream?

Tags: hadoop, orc

OrcFile reader have two params, file path and fileSystem Config, such like this:

```
Reader reader = OrcFile.createReader(path, OrcFile.readerOptions(config));
```

However I want to read a orcFile not on hadoop, just a local file,so there is no hdfs path for orcReader.

What should i do?

Comment: You can use `file://` as a Hadoop FileSystem Path

Comment: thx,but the file not on server,so i think it will throw file not found exception. I want to upload file to hdfs from local pc. Just like upload file from pc to server by spring boot.

Comment: That wasn't the original question, but you can also use the Hadoop Java API to `copyFromLocal` https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyFromLocalFile(boolean,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)

Comment: Did you find a solution?